# Запятая перед "и" в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Дорогой друг, оглянись (,) и ты увидишь, как прекрасна природа", запятая перед "и" нужна, потому что оно ССП? Правильно, что первая грамматическая снова "оглянись",  вторая "ты увидишь".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно, запятая ставится перед союзом И. Сложное предложение состоит из трех предложений, первое предложение связано сочинительной связью со вторым и третьим, связь между которыми является подчинительной. Основы первых двух предложений выделены правильно.